# Return contents of the cell above the one indicated in VLOOKUP using ADDRESS, INDEX, MATCH, and/or CELL function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am trying to use a date in Sheet 1 and using Vlookup to find this date on Sheet 2 and return the value/contents onto to a cell in sheet of the cell directly above that date in sheet 2.
[image: Sheet 1 Shows the Vlookup criteria for Sheet and the result which should be the cell directly above the VLOOKUP cell]

[image: Sheet 2 where we need to lookup the value of Sheet B9 and return the value on sheet 2 minus one cell.]

This is the Formula I used that you can see

```
=INDEX('AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000,MATCH($B$9,'AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000)-1)
```

I have tried using Index and match but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: what is the index match formula you tried that returned the `7/18/18`

Comment: or even the vlookup that you used.  we need something to help you.

Comment: use the third criterion in the Match: `=INDEX('AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000,MATCH($B$9,'AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000,0)-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
=INDEX('AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000,MATCH($B$9,'AUSSIE Dly'!$A$3:$A$2000, 0)-1)
```

The added zero indicates using an Exact Match.

Comment: Thank you Scott and Sancho!!!  That worked perfectly!!!